# How to checksum with sha256 or sha512 while using maven to download dependency package?

Tags: maven, sha256, checksum, sha512

I'm deploying a private repository. As we know, Maven uses md5 and sha1 to verify package checksum by default. What can I do if I want the Maven client to use sha256 or sha512 for checksum verification?

Comment: First what do you like to check the sha256 ? For what purpose and more important what kind of problem do you like to solve? Another important question: Have you configured the checkSum policy?